# Compare transition matrix elements in molecules and solids

Tags: solid-state-physics, optical-properties, organic-chemistry

Is there a general trend such that transition matrix elements for electronic/excitonic transitions are larger/smaller in molecules than in inorganic solids or vice versa?

Comment: +1 but from which vibrational level? Won't they be different at the bottom of a potential well vs the top?

Comment: Is this a question about differences between organic vs inorganic matter (where "inorganic" is a very broad category that comprises almost the entire periodic table) or is it a question about the transition from molecules to solids? I.e. would you be satisfied with an answer about the difference between molecules (gas? liquid?) and molecular crystals? (not that I know it off the top of my head)

Comment: it is a question about optical selection rules and absorption and how they are different in organic and inorganic semiconductors.

Comment: it is a question about electronic transitions in the systems where electrons are delocalized over long distances and where electrons are tightly confined.